# useContext is giving me problems with my react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, state-management, use-context

so I have this app file for react,

```
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([

  ])
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
      <Route  element={<Layout />}>
        <cartContext.Provider value={{ cart, setCart }}>{/* you wrap provider around the components that you want to have access to the state  */}
      
        <Route path="/" index element={<Home/>} />


        <Route path="Bracelets"  element={<Bracelets />} />

        <Route path="Signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="Login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="Cart"  element={<Cart />} />

        <Route path="Cart/shipping-buynow" element={<ShippingAddToCart />} />
        <Route path="/help" element={<Help />} />
        <Route path="/Modal" element={<Modal />} />
        <Route path="/Add" element={<Add />} />


        {/* <Route path="/create" element={<CreateMeet/>} /> */}
        {/* <Route path="/Register" element={<Register />} /> */}
        </cartContext.Provider>
      </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

but for some reason the useContext that I implemented is giving me an error

Error: [undefined] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

Comment: Hard to know exactly the issue here as you haven't shared the code for the context and how it is set up but usually the component name should just be cartContextProvider not cartContext.Provider.

It only appears as cartContext.Provider when you set it up but you render it as cartContextProvider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is giving you an `error` because of the `Routes tag`. In `version 6` of `react-router-dom` you can't put anything except `route` inside your `<Routes>...</Routes>` tag.

So use `useContext` like below:

```
<Router>
   <cartContext.Provider value={{ cart, setCart }}>
      <Routes>
        <Route ...>
      </Routes>
   </cartContext.Provider>
</Router>
```

It should solve your problem.